# Powershell - Variable scope behaves strangely

Tags: powershell, scope, powershell-3.0

I have a little script which  reads out members of an AD group and then I compare them to an array of users I have.

To accomplish this I use a couple of nested loops and if conditions and the big problem I'm facing is, that my `$members` variable suddenly loses scope and values to `null`.
I tried to set the scope to `$Global:members` or `$Script:members` which had no effect.

Following is the source code I have. Any suggestions, pushes in the right direction how to work around and help are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I piped the `$members` variable to `Out-String` which let me proceed with my work, still I am very curious about what happened, so if anyone knows what happened, please enlighten me.

```
foreach($group in $groups)
{
    #pull the members here
    $members = $group | Get-ADGroupMember | Out-String # Out-String fixed the issue

    $members #this little print shows me everything is alright 

    #pull a needed portion of every group for further matching
    if($group.Name -match "Group-AX_User_(.*)_Productive")
    {
        $man = $Matches[1]
    }

    foreach($entry in $result)
    {
        #each entry is a csv string, pull the first value
        if($entry -match ".*,`"(.*)`"")
        {
            $tblMan = $Matches[1]
            if($tblMan -eq $man)
            {
                #alrigth our group matches with the one in the csv
                #everything is fine, members is not null
                if($entry -match "`"(.*)`",`"")
                {
                    #!!! All of the sudden, $members is null
                    #what the hell happened?

                    $m = $Matches[1]
                    if($members.Contains($m))
                    {
                        #well the current entry member is
                        #already in the group
                        $entry
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $result is never defined, and we have no idea how $groups/$group is formatted, so this is virtually impossible to help troubleshoot since it doesn't work in general with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a scope issue. The issue is that you have a group that does not exist in the domain. So then you get to this line:

```
$members = $group | Get-ADGroupMember
```

You are assigning `$null` to `$members`.

The reason why piping it to Out-String worked for you is because that assigned a empty string into members. You logic just happens to not choke on that.

Even your sanity check was lying to you.

```
$members #this little print shows me everything is alright
```

It would print the members on the last loop just fine. On the current pass, null shows nothing. Then you would error on the `$members.Contains($m)` deeper in your script. You would see the previous output and it would give the impression that it lost scope.